# I am adding and removing textboxes on jsp page dynamically, I am getting extra null in spring controller for those objects which has been removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, jsp

I am adding and removing textboxes on jsp page dynamically, Suppose I've added 5 textboxes and removed 1st, 2nd, 3rd position(index starting from 0) textboxes, I am passing these data to my Spring Controller through javascript(serializeArray()), in controller I am getting list of 5 object where 1st, 2nd, 3rd are null.

I don't want all 5 objects list in controller, list should contain only 0th and 4th indexed object as 1st, 2nd, 3rd I already removed.

Code:jsp file

```
<div class="col-md-12 flat-row-0">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="flatNumber" class="normal">Flat Number<span
                            style="color: red;"> *</span></label>
                        <form:input type="text" class="form-control input-sm flat-number"
                            id="flatNumber" path="flatDetailsDTOs[0].flatNumber"
                            placeholder="Flat Number" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="flatType" class="normal">Flat Type<span
                            style="color: red;"> *</span></label>
                        <form:select class="form-control input-sm flat-type"
                            id="flatType" path="flatDetailsDTOs[0].flatType">
                            <form:option value="">Select</form:option>
                            <c:forEach var="entry" items="${FlatType.getFlatTypes()}">
                                <form:option style="color:black;" value="${entry.key}">${entry.value}</form:option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </form:select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="status" class="normal">Status<span
                            style="color: red;"> *</span></label>
                        <form:select class="form-control input-sm flat-status"
                            id="status" path="flatDetailsDTOs[0].status">
                            <form:option value="">Select</form:option>
                            <c:forEach var="entry"
                                items="${VacancyStatus.getVacancyStatus()}">
                                <form:option value="${entry.key}">${entry.value}</form:option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </form:select>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="flat-tab" style="display: none;">
                <div class="col-md-12 flat-row-0">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="flatNumber" class="normal">Flat Number<span
                                style="color: red;"> *</span></label>
                            <form:input type="text"
                                class="form-control input-sm flat-number" id="flatNumber"
                                path="flatDetailsDTOs[0].flatNumber" placeholder="Flat Number" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="flatType" class="normal">Flat Type<span
                                style="color: red;"> *</span></label>
                            <form:select class="form-control input-sm flat-type"
                                id="flatType" path="flatDetailsDTOs[0].flatType">
                                <form:option value="">Select</form:option>
                                <c:forEach var="entry" items="${FlatType.getFlatTypes()}">
                                    <form:option style="color:black;" value="${entry.key}">${entry.value}</form:option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </form:select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="status" class="normal">Status<span
                                style="color: red;"> *</span></label>
                            <form:select class="form-control input-sm flat-status"
                                id="status" path="flatDetailsDTOs[0].status">
                                <form:option value="">Select</form:option>
                                <c:forEach var="entry"
                                    items="${VacancyStatus.getVacancyStatus()}">
                                    <form:option value="${entry.key}">${entry.value}</form:option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </form:select>`enter code here`
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="close-button">
                        <i id="flat-row-0" class="fa fa-close"
                            style="margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 0px; cursor: pointer;"
                            onclick="removeFlatRow(this.id)"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

js:

```
var $setupForm = $('#ownerForm');
var flatCount = $("div[class*='flat-row-']").length - 2;

$("#addFlat").on("click", function() {
    flatCount = flatCount + 1;
    var clonedElement = $(".flat-tab").clone(true);
    clonedElement = clonedElement.html().replace(/0/g, flatCount);
    $(".flat-body").append(clonedElement);
});

function removeFlatRow(flatId) {
$('#loading').addClass('show');
$("."+flatId).remove();
$('#loading').removeClass('show');}

function() {
        $('#loading').addClass('show');
        $.post($setupForm.data('url'), $setupForm.find(':input:not(:hidden)').serializeArray()).done(
                function(response) {
                    $('#loading').removeClass('show');
                    if (response.status == true) {
                        $(".content-wrapper").load(
                                $setupForm.data('successUrl'));
                        showSuccessMsg(response.message);
                    } else {
                        showErrorMsg(response.message);
                    }
                })
    }
```

in controller:

```
flatDetailsDTOs=[FlatDetailsDTO [flatId=null, flatNumber=1001, flatType=TWO_BHK, status=FILLED], FlatDetailsDTO [flatId=null, flatNumber=null, flatType=null, status=null], FlatDetailsDTO [flatId=null, flatNumber=null, flatType=null, status=null], FlatDetailsDTO [flatId=null, flatNumber=null, flatType=null, status=null],FlatDetailsDTO [flatId=null, flatNumber=1002, flatType=ONE_BHK, status=VACANT]]]
```

Comment: When ever you use spring's form tag you need to understand that PATH attribute gets converted as NAME attribute in html and that name will be used to map the model in spring controller. When you remove the field you are leaving the index in array which spring will treat as null. I would suggest you to manipulate the indexes in name attribute in html

Comment: you are right @SahilShaikh, but how to manipulate indexes?

Comment: Two ways. You can either reindex the inputs on each remove or before the submit of form make your own form data using javascript/jQuery and then submit